# How to use multiple $content_for_layout

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp and I think I've run into my first problem because  I need 2 $content_for_layout in my default layout, like this:

```
<div id="left_collumn"> 
    <?php echo $content1_for_layout ?> 
</div> 
<div id="right_column"> 
   <?php echo $content2_for_layout ?> 
</div>
```

I've searched this group and found a thread that suggest using this : http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rtconner/2007/08/28/anything_for_layout-making-html-from-the-view-available-to-the-layout   and even though I followed the instructions for some reason  this is what I always get :http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3246/sshot1duh.jpg
[image]

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please post the code from your view and from your layout file.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe you could use an element instead...

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements

Answer (score 0):

Read about plugins, thats not the way! Lear to make your own plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you should use elements instead. Try to go with the rules of the framework whenever you are working on it. There is no need to change the way how Cake PHP handles it, rather using the solutions which framework offers. Use Elements.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements